# What to do to Admob adView when Android device changes orientation?

Tags: android, orientation, admob

Orientation change recreates current activity, so adview etc are added again, if user rotates the phone a few times, won't it trigger some "evil" algorithms on Admob's side to determine if the developer is cheating/refreshing more quicker than it should be, etc..

Should i make AdView static and re-add it to the view on every oncreate? If so, instead of adding adView programmatically, i could add it with xml? In that case i couldn't even set it as a static variable and it would load adView on every orientation change.

I am using it programmatically and i plan to keep it like this.

What should i do, what is the best / preferred way for managing adView on rotation changes?

Answer (score 0):

Once you include    android:configChanges="orientation" in your current Activity code of the     AndroidManifest.xml file. The same activity will remain with orientation change. And it wont recreate the activity again. So the same Ad will remain without increasing your Ad Request unseemly.

Comment: But that will cause the ad not to adapt its size to the new layout, as seen in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20929963/admob-ad-not-resizing-correctly-upon-screen-orientation-includes-pictures/23799772#23799772