# Admob ad not resizing correctly upon screen orientation [Includes Pictures]

Tags: java, android, admob

I am using Admob for ads in my app and I ran into a problem. Whenever I turn the screen to landscape mode, the ad shows up but it's the same size as it was in portrait mode. This problem occured after I added this xml declaration in my manifest to my main activity that was necessary to keep the main parts of the app functioning smoothly:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
```

I am using smart banner in my ad for the size:

```
ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
```

I have attached pictures of this problem:

[image: This is what it looks like in portrait mode. It runs perfectly]
[image: This is what it looks like after I turn my phone sideways. The ad still shows but it doesn't resize to the fill width]

What do I have to do to get the ad to resize properly in landscape mode without deleting

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
```

in the manifest for my main activity?

Comment: The first picture is what my ad looks like in portrait which is good but the second picture shows what it looks like in landscape mode which is bad because it's not resizing correctly.

Comment: Potential duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11281562/android-admob-resize-on-landscape

Answer (score 8):

this is how I solved it:

```
@Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        orientation_changed = true;
        renewAd();
    }

    private void renewAd() {
        AdView ad = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView); 
        LayoutParams lp = (LayoutParams) ad.getLayoutParams();
        // change relative layout for your layout which contains the adView
        RelativeLayout parent = (RelativeLayout) ad.getParent();
        parent.removeView(ad);      
        AdView newAd = new AdView(this, AdSize.SMART_BANNER, "YOUR ID");
        newAd.setId(R.id.adView);
        newAd.setLayoutParams(lp);      
        parent.addView(newAd);      
        newAd.loadAd(new AdRequest());
    }
```

regards

Comment: Actually, that AdView constructor is not available in the current SDK

Answer (score 8):

In line with other responses (but updating them to the current AdMob SDK -v7.5-, and providing the full code), the onConfigurationChanged() method of the activity needs to include the destruction and creation of the Ad View:

```
// Remove the ad keeping the attributes
AdView ad = (AdView) myactivity.findViewById(R.id.adView);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) ad.getLayoutParams();
LinearLayout parentLayout = (LinearLayout) ad.getParent();
parentLayout.removeView(ad);

// Re-initialise the ad
ad.destroy();
ad = new AdView(parent);
ad.setAdSize(com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
ad.setAdUnitId(myactivity.getString(R.string.banner_ad_unit_id));
ad.setId(R.id.adView);
ad.setLayoutParams(lp);
parentLayout.addView(ad);

// Re-fetch add and check successful load
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
    .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
    .addTestDevice(parent.getString(R.string.test_device_id))
    .build();
```

Comment: That is the correct behaviour. The height in landscape is scarce, so the ad becomes shorter to make more screen real state available to the user.

Comment: why do you need `AdView ad = (AdView) myactivity.findViewById(R.id.adView);` if you have `mAdView`?

Comment: @user25 good catch; this was a copy/paste issue when posting the answer here.