# Adview Size Smart_Banner broke when change orientation

Tags: android, android-layout, admob, android-studio-2.0, adview

I'm facing a problem that happen when I change orientation screen, the smart_banner doesn't refreshing.

I search about and smart_banner should automatically refresh the banner's size, but they aren't doing this and I can't figure out why.

**EDIT: HOW I SOLVE THE PROBLEM**

I just remove, re-bind and re-add my Adview through the code on onConfigurationChanged():

```
@Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Remove the ad keeping the attributes
        AdView ad = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.ad_view_home);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) (ad != null ? ad.getLayoutParams() : null);
        RelativeLayout parentLayout = (RelativeLayout) (ad != null ? ad.getParent() : null);
        if (parentLayout != null) {
            parentLayout.removeView(ad);
        }

        // Re-initialise the ad
        mAdView.destroy();
        mAdView = new AdView(this);
        mAdView.setAdSize(com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
        mAdView.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.banner_ad_unit_id_home));
        mAdView.setId(R.id.ad_view_home);
        mAdView.setLayoutParams(lp);
        if (parentLayout != null) {
            parentLayout.addView(mAdView);
        }

        // Re-fetch add and check successful load
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                .addTestDevice(getString(R.string.device_id_test1))
                .build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
        mAdView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                super.onAdLoaded();
                Utils.setLayoutVisible(mAdView);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdFailedToLoad(int i) {
                super.onAdFailedToLoad(i);
                Utils.setLayoutInvisible(mAdView);
            }
        });
    }
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
 <activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
```

I'm setup adview in XML:

```
    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="br.com.adley.myseriesproject.activities.HomeActivity">
        <content here...>
        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/ad_view_home"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id_search_show"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

In acitivy, I setup like this:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        activateToolbarWithNavigationView(HomeActivity.this);

        //Ad Config
        // Initialize the Mobile Ads SDK.
        MobileAds.initialize(this, getString(R.string.application_id_ad));

        // Gets the ad view defined in layout/ad_fragment.xml with ad unit ID set in
        // values/strings.xml.
        mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.ad_view_home);

        // Create an ad request. Check your logcat output for the hashed device ID to
        // get test ads on a physical device. e.g.
        // "Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("ABCDEF012345") to get test ads on this device."
        mAdRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                .addTestDevice(getString(R.string.device_id_test1))
                .build();

        // Start loading the ad in the background.
        mAdView.loadAd(mAdRequest);
        mAdView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                super.onAdLoaded();
                Utils.setLayoutVisible(mAdView);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdFailedToLoad(int i) {
                super.onAdFailedToLoad(i);
                Utils.setLayoutInvisible(mAdView);
            }
        });

        // Tabs Setup
        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.home_pager);
        if (tabLayout != null) {
            tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(getString(R.string.favorites_label_fragment)));
            tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(getString(R.string.air_today_label_fragment)));
            tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
            final HomePageAdapter adapter = new HomePageAdapter
                    (getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
            if (viewPager != null) {
                viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
                viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
                tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_home_settings, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_refresh) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

And here is my gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "br.com.adley.myseriesproject"
            minSdkVersion 17
            targetSdkVersion 23
            versionCode 7
            versionName "Beta 5.0"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

   dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'org.ini4j:ini4j:0.5.4'
    compile 'jp.wasabeef:picasso-transformations:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.0.0'
    // http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.balysv/material-ripple
    compile group: 'com.balysv', name: 'material-ripple', version: '1.0.2'

}

    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Did you call the adView.resume() and adView.pause() methods in your Activity?

Comment: Yes, I've update my question.

Comment: re-order the super.onPause() and mAdView.pause() And always call super methods first.

Comment: I've re-ordered but it still not working. The size doesn't change.

Comment: re-order in your super calls in AdListener

Comment: Ops, I didn't saw. I've re-ordered too, but still doesn't work.

Comment: can you add your code in the beginning of onCreate()

Comment: Yes, also you can check all code here: [HomeActivity - GitHub](https://github.com/adleywd/WhatsNextSeries/blob/master/app/src/main/java/br/com/adley/myseriesproject/activities/HomeActivity.java)

Comment: I add my gradle, I don't know if the version can be a problem. add the important part of main code.

Comment: check if admob sdk needs to be updated

Comment: I check this in sdk manager?

Comment: I've followed this docs https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the AdView size doesn't get changed, but  with the SMART_BANNER is still for a full width ad in the new orientation, and so it doesn't fit.I think recreation the AdView in this case may be easier for you to do in code than via XML.

[Admob ad not resizing correctly upon screen orientation [Includes Pictures]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20929963/admob-ad-not-resizing-correctly-upon-screen-orientation-includes-pictures/29516024#29516024)

Hope this helps..

Comment: I've tried to do this via code, but I had problems with parameters, like align bottom and heigh and width, but I mix some answers and it worked! I'll edit my question to post the right solution and mark yours as correct, ty.